# (go) off the boil

Tags: expressions, idioms, british-english, metaphors

"(go)off the boil" seems to mean "past the crisis" in British English.

What is the origin/etymology of this expression? Is it used nowadays?

Comment: When the bubbles stop coming up, a previously boiling liquid is said to have gone off the boil. This happens after heating is stopped, but not immediately; there is always a delay caused by thermal hysteresis.

Comment: It doesn't only mean "past the crisis". It is frequently used to mean something is not performing as well as it did. *Manchester United have gone off the boil since Ferguson retired*.

Answer (score 1):

Originally an expression of the kitchen. If you have to boil some substance in hot water for a long time and the fire goes out the water goes off the boil, ie stops boiling. 
An expression that can be used as a metaphor. A typical example for the use of this expression I have read in a novel:
An American senator is having sex with a young lady. Then the phone begins ringing in the next room. He knows that it is an important call and goes into the other room. On the phone he says: Make it short, or the young lady I have in bed will go off the boil.

A pity that I have forgotten what novel it was.

Comment: *American Gods*, Neil Gaiman maybe? - Wednesday to Shadow, "I don't sleep. It's overrated. A bad habit I do my best to avoid - in company, wherever possible, and the young lady may go off the boil if I don't get back to her."

Comment: Thanks, Catija, your quote is almost the same. What I read  was a thriller with the daughter of a senator as the central  person of the novel, and the relation between daughter and father isn't very good. I must have the book around here, but there are too many books around.

Answer (score 1):

I think one reason that it may be a metaphor in Britain, Australia and New Zealand, is because we are tea-drinking nations. And, as anyone who knows how to make a nice cup of tea will tell you, the water (unlike with coffee making) has to be boiling.

I have never had a nice cup of tea in America, nor in France, nor in Germany. But Down-Under in the Outback, the *Rosie Lea* comes out of the pot just like it does in Old Blighty. And tea is very important. When England and Australia are playing cricket for the coveted Ashes, (during a hot summer of 5 five-day matches) as they are at the moment, cricket is always interrupted for half-an-hour at 4.00pm, for the *tea interval*. Nothing is allowed to get in the way of a cup of tea.

Now the most frequent error when making tea is to allow the water to ***go off the boil***. I remember having this drummed into me as a child. Thus the expression *off the boil* is well understood, which may explain its extension into the metaphoric.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard it but my first thought was that it relates to a boiling pot of water that has settled down.

Boiling water is very active and unpredictable... when you turn the heat off, it "comes off a boil" meaning that when additional energy (heat) is no longer added to water, it causes the water to return to a calm state.

Sure enough, that seems to be the case, as you can see [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_off_the_boil):

> - (UK, Australia) Cease to boil when heat is no longer applied.
>
>   - *That is the reason for the coin. You will be able to hear it dancing about, and it will tell you if the water **goes off the boil** or is getting dangerously low.* - *The Cuisines of Mexico*, Diana Kennedy and Craig Claibourne, 1972
> - (idiomatic, UK, Australia) To lose interest; to pall.
>
>   - *By then we'd **gone off the boil** sexually and he was even less keen than I was about 'marriedness', so it was more like friends deciding to share a flat than the setting-up of a ménage.* - *Somewhere Towards the End: A Memoir*, Diana Athill, 2009
> - (idiomatic, UK, Australia) To become of diminished intensity or urgency.
> - (idiomatic, UK, Australia) To become less successful.